# Why does a dart HttpClient get request take 17 sec to a localhost server?

Tags: flutter, dart, https

```
var client = new HttpClient();
client.badCertificateCallback = ((X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true);
print("Connecting to: https://192.168.100.200:8081/zoneserver/?op=1&id=$id");
Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch()..start();
var request = await client.getUrl(Uri.parse("https://192.168.100.200:8081/zoneserver/?op=1&id=$id"));
print("Got request ${stopwatch.elapsed}");
request.persistentConnection = false;  // Use non-persistent connection.
var response = await request.close();
print("Got response ${stopwatch.elapsed}");
var contents = await response.transform(utf8.decoder).join();
print("Got contents ${stopwatch.elapsed}");
client.close();
print("${stopwatch.elapsed} content:$contents");
```

Why is this code so slow? The server is basically a hello world server and is run locally. Using Postman or a web browser the request is instant.

I am testing on Android 11 device. My suspicion is that it is the `client.badCertificateCallback`. But why, and is there something I can do about it?

Edit: It is the `var request = await client.getUrl(Uri.parse("https://192.168.100.200:8081/zoneserver/?op=1&id=$id"));` that takes 17 seconds

Comment: Have you added some logging (with timestamps there matches your client part) to your server to see what takes times in the communication? E.g. can you see your server receiving the request the exact same time as Dart is sending it?

Comment: I do the logging you see in the code snippet and also log on server side when a new request is received. It is the client.getUrl() that takes time ~17sec. The server receives the request ~17sec after the call to client.getUrl(). I will add some more logging: connected, handshake etc